# Buttons visible on all tabs when copied

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, tabcontrol

When I'm in Access and using a Tab Control, if I copy a button on one tab and paste it to the same tab, this button becomes visible on all tabs.  In fact, I think all controls do (I know it happened with buttons and labels).

Is there a way to fix this, or do I have to delete the copied controls and re-draw them on the tab they're supposed to be visible on?  Is there a setting that fixes this?  I've got a few pages where it'd be handy to be able to copy a chunk of controls and paste them onto a different tab.

Comment: Are you sure that the tab control had the focus when you did the paste? If the form was in focus it would get pasted to the form which wouldf explain why the button is visible everywhere.

Comment: Well, it showed the tab as active and in focus, but I discovered that if I right-click on the tab name and choose "Paste", then it will paste it onto the tab.  I was just right-clicking and choosing "Paste" from anywhere on the form because the tab was showing as active and I figured it'd end up there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old issue that needs to be closed out. The OP @Johnny Bones talks about his answer in the comments but never posted what he did to fix it as an answer.

The answer is that the object was pasted in at the wrong level, the form level. Form level objects are seen on every Tab Page.

To fix this

1. Cut the object again
2. Select the Tab Page you want the object to live inside
3. Paste it there
4. Move it to the correct location